# Find my element has `inline` style applied

Tags: jquery

I have an element, from the element how do i know whether it has the `inline` style applied or not?

example :

html :

```
<span style="border:1px solid red;">Testing</span>
//<span>Testing</span> //without style as well getting some in build info
```

js :

```
var sty = $('span').prop('style');
console.log(sty); //it always consoles something!
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgv74ew1/)

Comment: It always returns a styleDeclaration object, containing the elements native styles and any you've added

Comment: yes, but i would like to remove the element which contains the inline style attribute applied

Comment: `$('span[style]').remove()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sty = $('span').is('[style]');
if(sty)
{
  //style is present
}
else
{
  //style is not present
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zgv74ew1/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('span').hasAttr("style")) {
    console.log("element 'span' has a style attribute");
}
```

EDIT: I was in a hurry and forgot to add the `hasAttr` function, sorry :)

```
$.fn.hasAttr = function(){
        if (this.attr('style') !== "undefined") {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

To be honest, you could just use `if($("span").attr('style') !== undefined)`

Comment: it seems there is no `hasAttr`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
if(typeof($('span').attr('style'))==typeof('undefined') && $('span').attr('style')==undefined)
```