# jQuery check if div has inline style

Tags: jquery, css

I want to check if div#content has inline style, if so to find it's parent div with attribute id, and add a class. here is my layout!

```
<div id="one">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <div class="content" style="display:block"></div>
</div>
 <div id="three">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

In this case I'm trying to find div#two and add a class there, but find out with attribut id

thank you,

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. I suggest you to read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find my element has \`inline\` style applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123796/find-my-element-has-inline-style-applied)

Comment: While this is certainly possible, it seems like a less than ideal X/Y problem. Can't you apply the class when the inline style is added?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop `'.content'` DOM and check if `display=inline` then [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```js
$('.content').each(function() {
if($(this).css('display') == 'inline')
{
  $(this).parent().addClass("classAdd");
}
});
```

```css
.content{
display:inline;
}
.classAdd{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <div class="content" style="display:block"></div>
</div>
 <div id="three">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: just as a question - should coding-service styled questions be answered? (not trying to be .. douchey, just wanna know for the future #ModInTheMaking)

Comment: @Nick that's why it's just a question ;) but ty for the link - interesting read :)

Comment: You can create the future(by start develope this service) or wait to th future :)... my recommand go on the first one

Comment: valid point, though would it not be better to start a conversion in a chat room with the user rather than post code? Again not trying to be douchey haha just would like to know :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use - checking css will not help, you need to check .attr("style") to check if inline style attribute is mentioned in element.

```
$('.content').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
  if($this.attr('style')){
    console.log($(this).attr('style'));
    $this.parent().addClass("class-new");
  }
});
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vda6yus1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
$('.content').each(function() {
  if($(this).is('[style]'))
  {
    $(this).parent().addClass("classNew");
  }
});
```

```css
.classNew{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <div class="content" style="display:block"></div>
</div>
 <div id="three">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```